# UV map distorting on flat face

Tags: uv

[image]

As you can see in the picture I have flat faces mapped to a texture but on the model they're being distorted (especially around G2 and G3). I've tried things like triangulating my mesh and adjusting the mapping and unwrapping types but no luck.

Please any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

I've noticed the shapes don't match, if I ask blender to unwrap that face only it gives me a wrong looking shape:

[image]

If I project from view it seems to give a much better appropriation of the shape:

[image]

Comment: the profile on G3 (bottom right cube) does not seem to correspond to the UV map on G3... did you moved the vertices in the 3D view after the uv unwrap ?

Comment: No, good catch tho I just updated the main question

Comment: is the face flat in the image of your edit ? If yes, how did you unwrap ? project from view ?

Comment: I had that face selected, pressed u and then used unwrap. If I use project from view that gives a better shape, updated question

Comment: yes "project from view", if you are face to the face in ortho (and select only the wanted face) will allow you to have the exact same positions

Comment: Be sure to make the project from view from the 3D **ortho** view